# Azure devop server users not get email notifications

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have users with emails notifications setup and they are not getting those notifications.  If I go into the job monitor I can see that the email notification job was partially successful and when looking at the details I see several users are filtered.
CheckinEvent result Filtered !Recipient xxx was filtered !Recipient xxx was filtered !Recipient xxx was filtered !Recipient xxx was filtered !Altered event is null for event 154379 of type CheckinEvent 15:33:49.3962322:Previous job run succeeded. 15:33:49.3962322:Current job run succeeded.   The xxx is where I blocked out usernames.  The people that it says are filtered are the same ones not receiving notifications.  And there are no failures listed, just filtered.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, since the e-mail was filtered.

> **Please check if those users have permission to see the event artifact.**
>
> Recipients who don't have permission to view the artifact, don't
>   receive an email, which contains event artifact data, such as a work
>   item.
>
> The only way to know if an email was filtered is to view notification
>   delivery logs.

Also this one:

> **Is this a team subscription, which contains a "@Me" filter clause?**
>
> If a team or group subscription has an @Me filter clause and the
>   target email recipients are in an AD group, no members of the AD group
>   match the filter clause. AD groups aren't expanded for filter
>   matching.

More detail ways for troubleshooting, please kindly refer our official doc-- [Not getting emails from subscriptions or notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/troubleshoot-not-getting-email?view=azure-devops)

Besides, if you want analysis more info, you could also give a try with  [enabling and retrieving subscription and delivery logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/use-subscription-logging?view=azure-devops).