# How to use job monitor to check whether emails have been sent by Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I'm facing the issue that I can't get email notification from Azure DevOps.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503030/azure-devop-server-users-not-get-email-notifications/67401881#67401881) and learnt that there is a **job monitor** that can check whether Azure DevOps has sent the emails.

> If I go into the job monitor I can see that the email notification job was partially successful...

I want to know how could I get the **job monitor** and how to use it.

By the way, I have done some checkings following [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/troubleshoot-not-getting-email?view=azure-devops) but the issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how could I get the job monitor and how to use it.

The job monitor is a monitoring dashboard dedicated to TFS. If you are using the azure devops service, I am afraid you cannot use the job monitor. As far as I know, it is impossible to check whether the email is sent in the azure devops service. Please refer to this [blog](https://pserranne.wordpress.com/2015/03/20/a-tfs-gem-hidden-monitoring-dashboard/).

You can first go to your personal subscriptions and locate the subscription, which you feel should have produced an email and ensure it's enabled.

[image]

[image]